# How to get test coins for local ETH testnet?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, remix, geth

Sorry for this may be a silly question to someone but I have actually searched around for quite a bit but couldn't figure it out.

I have setup a local ETH chain using geth with two nodes. The chain seems to be running well and the miner node kept printing it had mined blocks. MetaMask also connected to the chain successfully. However, I couldn't figure out how to fill the MetaMask test accounts with some test coins. All the information I found on the web was about using other testnet instead of local self setup testnet.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Though it now reports a different error "header not found", but seems it can find the test coins now. Thanks.

Comment: Realized that geth actually inited coins well in the genesis file, but I should have used the Import function in MetaMask to connect to the right address to get the coins out.